# How can I run a sidekiq worker a certain number of times per day, based on database column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

My Project model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  enum :number_of_samples, { once_per_day: 0, three_times_per_day: 1, hourly: 2 }, prefix: true
end
```

The sidekiq worker:

```
class PagespeedWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  
  def perform
    puts 'Beginning Fetching...'
    projects = ...
    projects.each do |project|
      sitemap = ...
      sitemap.each do |url|
        retrieve_data(...)
      end
    end
    puts 'Fetching done!'
  end
end
```

I want to be able to run the worker, based on the `number_of_samples` in the Project model.
It should run for every project, for every url in the project, the number of times per day specified in the `number_of_samples` field.

Comment: Probably with some customisations to schedule.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `number_of_samples` property to loop

Sample code

```rb
projects.each do |project|
  project.number_of_samples.times do
    sitemap_path = project.sitemap_path
    sitemap = SitemapParseService.call(sitemap_path)
    sitemap.each do |url|
      retrieve_data(url, 'desktop', project.id)
      retrieve_data(url, 'mobile', project.id)
    end
  end
end
```